# npm is not installed, but still showing version on npm -v

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I completely removed npm and nodejs from system, but it still shows the version.

For example - With the following command

```
    sudo apt-get purge npm
```

It shows - Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed.
But on using the below command.

```
    npm -v
```

it still shows the npm version

I expect, it should prompt me that npm is not installed on using

```
    npm -v
```

but it's showing the version. I am confused Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM can be installed by a different package manager or not managed by any package manager, thus still running.

The first step is to find where is your npm installed, the following command will help you:

```
which npm
```

It will probably still exist in one of the standard paths, and thus you can uninstall just removing all it's folders. This command bellow removes all files and folders related to node and npm from some possible locations:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node* /usr/local/include/node* /usr/local/bin/node*
```